# Removing bulk from custom default Spring validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling

I am writing some basic validation for properties with custom @NotNull messages read from messages.properties. The messages are read fine however the bulk of the default Spring error message remains as follows:

```
 "Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method: public java.lang.String uk.co.schedulerapi.Scheduler_Rest_Controller.bookAppointment(uk.co.apidefinitions.BookAppointment) throws java.lang.Exception, with 1 error(s): [Field error in object 'bookAppointment' on field 'windowStart': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.bookAppointment.windowStart,NotNull.windowStart,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [bookAppointment.windowStart,windowStart]; arguments []; default message [windowStart]]; default message [windowStart parameter is required]] "
```

Is it possible to remove all of the error message and leave my custom message without string parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using global exception handler.
Here is the way to handle it.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);


@ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class})
public void handleException(HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) {
    //build your custom message
    prepareErrorResponse(response,UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,yourCustomMessage);
}



private void prepareErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse response, HttpStatus status, String apiError) {
    response.setStatus(status.value());
    try(PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, apiError);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Error writing string to response body", ex);
    }
}
```